# Unity & Azure Spatial Anchors - The SpatialAnchorManager suddenly disappears?

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I am developing a Hololens 2 application in Unity following the Azure Spatial Anchor tutorials provided by Microsoft. [Specifically, this one uses Unity, the Mixed Reality Toolkit, and OpenXR.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-unity-hololens-app?tabs=azure-portal)

I have one scene where I am placing the Spatial Anchors (called "Edit Mode") and another where I am able to view the anchors that have been placed (called "Preview Mode"). Each scene has a script that allows the user to travel between scenes at the click of a button.

In both scenes, the `SpatialAnchorManager` exists in the same game object as the calling script, and is referenced like this:

```
private SpatialAnchorManager anchorManager;

void Start()
{
   anchorManager = GetComponent<SpatialAnchorManager>();
}
```

The `SpatialAnchorManager` is able to be successfully found this way, the session starts, and I can successfully move from the first scene ("Edit Mode") to the second one ("Preview Mode") using the code below.

```
public void moveToPreview()
{
  if(anchorManager.IsSessionStarted)
  { 
    anchorManager.DestroySession();
  }
  SceneManager.LoadScene("PreviewScene");
}
```

The "Preview Mode" scene has the exact same code, but it just points back to the "Edit Mode" scene; however, when I try to go back to "Edit Mode", the `SpatialAnchorManager` that already exists in "Preview Mode" cannot be found. (The exception I implemented is thrown.)

```
public void moveToEdit()
{
  if(anchorManager == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("Somehow the manager is not here.");
  }

  if(anchorManager.IsSessionStarted)
  { 
    anchorManager.DestroySession();
  }
  SceneManager.LoadScene("EditScene");
}
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Unity 2021.3.4f1
Azure Spatial Anchors SDK v. 2.13.0

Answer (score 0):

From reviewing above, I believe you are stating that this line is executing:

```
  if(anchorManager == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("Somehow the manager is not here.");
  }
```

What is likely to happen is each scene is getting a copy of the script which means two anchorManager variables.  You should be able to see that in Unity debugger.

Comment: Yes, that line is executing. But each scene has a different script running the same code and, in this iteration, each scene also has a different 'SpatialAnchorManager' object it is referring to. In Unity, do all scenes, objects, and scripts share the same symbol table? Would the variable in a symbol table of one script in one scene transfer over to another?

Comment: For this one, I believe you are wanting to share the same variable across the scenes which means a static or global variable.   Can use a singleton pattern or  change variable to have static modifier  (ie, public static SpatialAnchorManager anchorManager;)    For Unity, here are some pointers on how to do this since this is more of Unity question versus Azure Spatial Anchors:  https://answers.unity.com/questions/50716/how-to-make-a-global-variable-in-unity.html